# material-ui menu not close when dialog open

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am using react + material-ui .
i created `dialog` component in jsx file like this:

```
   export default class CartoviewAbout extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {open: false};
        }

        _handleOpen() {
            this.setState({open: true});
        };

        _handleClose() {
            this.setState({open: false});
        };

        render() {
            const actions = [
                <FlatButton
                    label="Close"
                    primary={true}
                    keyboardFocused={true}
                    onTouchTap={this._handleClose.bind(this)}
                />,
            ];

            return (
                <div>
                    <MenuItem
                        onTouchTap={this._handleOpen.bind(this)}
                        primaryText="Show About Dialog"
                    />
                    <Dialog
                        title={title}
                        actions={actions}
                        modal={false}
                        open={this.state.open}
                        onRequestClose={this._handleClose.bind(this)}
                        autoScrollBodyContent={true}
                        contentClassName="dialog"
                        bodyClassName="dialog_body"
                    >
                        <div ><p>{abstract}</p>
                        </div>
                    </Dialog>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

and i use this component in menu in another file but then i click the menu item dialog open and menu not close:

```
export default class CartoviewAppBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
     const about = appConfig.showAbout ? React.createElement(CartoviewAbout) : "";
     const icon_menu = <IconMenu
            iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
            anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
            targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
        >
            {about}
        </IconMenu>;
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar
                    title={''}
                    showMenuIconButton={false}
                    iconElementRight={icon_menu}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

image:[image]
i want menu to close when dialog open

Comment: Can you show your complete components of what you created and where it's not working as expected?

Comment: I mean the code :), not the views.

Comment: Can you show the _handleOpen function?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja updated

Comment: And your component with `IconMenu` ?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja done

Comment: I can see a <div> tag wrapping your menuItem component 'CartoviewAbout'.. I had the same issue.. when i place 'MenuItem' directly inside 'IconMenu' It resolved for me..

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to add the Dialog component outside the IconMenu. The IconMenu's onRequestChange event wont fire until the dialog closes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be a workaround.

```
 _handleOpen() {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({open: true});
    }, 100); //any arbitary timeout
 };
```

`MenuItem` `onClick` will automatically trigger for closing `IconMenu`

I think opening `Dialog` suppressing the event for closing `IconMenu`. So opening `Dialog` after closing `IconMenu` using `setTimeout`